# Remove white border for iphone / ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, web

http://www.myobgyn.ca/demo789/desktop/index4sdm.html

Looks good on desktop and designed to be pixil perfect and not extend on desktop.  However, on iphone / ipad, I would like it to extend out to full width automatically.  I don't want a mobile version, but simple for it to display full screen on iphone / ipad; but also have fixed pixil width desktop.

```
meta id='viewport' name="viewport" content="width=device-width"
```

I have tried multipe VIEWPORT tags, (scale etc, defined width)  current am only using the below, and its not working in portrait. pixil width of app is 580

on iPhone 5S it scrolls in portrait, but fits screen in landscape..

Also, device has a roller at bottom that user moves.  Unofrtunately, that movement at edge of screen triggers the ios swipe to open the next safari pages.. can I turn that feature off.

Comment: Post your code -- links to live sites die and change easily, decreasing the value of these resources over time and for other users experiencing similar problems.